# Time Space Complexity of Recursive Functions

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

This is from a leetcode problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-string/solution/

Write a function that reverses a string. The input string is given as an array of characters char[].

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

Example:

```
Input: ["h","e","l","l","o"]
Output: ["o","l","l","e","h"]
```

Solution 1:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseString(self, s):
        def helper(left, right):
            if left < right:
                s[left], s[right] = s[right], s[left]
                helper(left + 1, right - 1)

        helper(0, len(s) - 1)
```

Time complexity : O(N) time to perform N/2 swaps.
Space complexity : O(N) to keep the recursion stack.

Solution2:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseString(self, s):
        left, right = 0, len(s) - 1
        while left < right:
            s[left], s[right] = s[right], s[left]
            left, right = left + 1, right - 1
```

Time complexity: O(N) to swap N/2 element.
Space complexity: O(1), it's a constant space solution.

Can someone please explain why the space complexity in solution 2 is O(1) while the space complexity in solution 1 is O(n)?

Is it because solution 1 requires a function call?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The stack size of your program will depend on the input size.

Comment: Not really related to the question, but why on Earth would you wrap this in a class? The functions may not be pure (mutates the input) but there's no state! Pylint will even warn you that the method could be a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a function recursively, behind the scenes a new stack frame is created to hold the return address and variables you create in the new call.

Each recursive call does this, so if a function calls itself n/2 times, that's O(n) storage space.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.